# Make a custom language based on international English

Tags: sitecore-commerce, multilingual

Is there any way in Sitecore to build a custom language which is based on international English and uses all the same settings as en?

I basically just want to have a new identifier for the language versions to differentiate from en (which is used elsewhere).

The site is hosted on Azure App Services (IaaS) and [I'm aware of the limitation on creating custom locales on App Services](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/how-to-add-custom-language-to-sitecore-on-azure-paas-web-apps).

**EDIT**

I created a new language and reset its properties to match international English.
I couldn't rename it in Sitecore as this is disallowed but could rename with a simple SQL query.

Unfortunately, the new language is not supported by the content editor and I cannot create versions with that language as it does not appear in the language dropdown.

Comment: For some reason, Sitecore's concept of "languages" is tightly coupled to the underlying .NET CultureInfo mechanics. I've never really understood why, but it will get in the way of what you're trying to do here. That said, "Languages are not markets". If I were you I would consider segmenting your content on proper mechanics, not rely on artificial "languages" and/or fallbacks. It leads to hell.

Comment: @MarkCassidy If in saying " segmenting your content on proper mechanics" you mean having distinct content branches, then yes I agree. We are already doing that.

The problem here is that we are using Sitecore Commerce where a product could be in international English for one site, and require a *different* English version for another English language site (which does not fit into the standard list of cultures).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily go "different content branches". But this is turning into more of a conversation, less of narrowing in on an actual answer. Happy to discuss more on Slack.